# Using variable in Angular (8) partial class name

Tags: angular

I want to create dynamic class names like

```
<div [ngClass]='color-42'>
<div [ngClass]='color-43'>
```

through using

`<div [ngClass]="color-{{variable}}">`

or variants thereof
but all I get is matching variants of

```
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column ...
```

Comment: Try `<div [ngClass]="'color-' + variable">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use curly brackets with input attributes.

You should either use one of them:

```
[ngClass]="'color-' + variable"
```

Or:

```
class="color-{{variable}}"
```

Or:

```
[ngClass]="{'color-' + variable: someExpression}"
```

Official docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description